# Render HTML in Javascript without Changing the DOM

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, dom

I doubt this is possible, but I'll ask anyway.

Let's say I have a custom HTML tag "location", that I want to render a certain way, without actually altering the DOM.

For example: `<location loc-id="14" address="blah" zipcode="14" />`

Would render the equivalent of:

```
<div class="location">
    <div>Blah></div>
    <div>14></div>
</div>
```

I know I could extract the data from the attributes, and generate new DOM elements accordingly, but I'd like to do it without actually adding/editing the DOM.

Again, I doubt it's possible, but I'd figured I'd ask.

Comment: The DOM is the basis of the page layout. Whatever you do, you can't change one without changing the other.

Comment: no... you can't do it.... without altering the dom...

Comment: You need to look into [the X-Tag stuff](https://hacks.mozilla.org/2013/05/speed-up-app-development-with-x-tag-and-web-components/). You *can* (or, at least, you'll soon be able to) do it without having to retroactively perform surgery on the DOM, and I think that's kind-of what you mean here.

Comment: Your question makes me think of Shadow DOM: http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/webcomponents/shadowdom/

Comment: Why do you not want to alter the DOM? You could always put your content in an iframe so that the DOM of the original document stays the same and your rendered content goes in the iframe DOM.

Comment: Is the custom tag in the DOM?  What do you want to do if not alter the DOM, write the HTML to the console?

Comment: It looks like these Shadow DOM suggestions were exactly what I was looking for.  Unfortunately, it doesn't look like I'll be using them anytime soon.  To answer your question, Jason, I have a WYSIWYG editor, that includes an HTML editor.  I wanted to create custom tags so that I could have them rendered one way in the WYSIWYG portion, and in a single element form in the HTML editor.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use the css :before and :after pseudo elements to do this:

```
<style>
  location:before {
    content: attr(address);
    text-transform: capitalize;
    display: block;
  }

  location:after {
    content: attr(zipcode);
    display: block;
  }
</style>
<location loc-id="14" address="blah" zipcode="14" />
```

Displays as:

```
Blah
14
```

Comment: This sufficiently answers the question, as asked.  Thanks!